prove some inequalities
I am facing trouble in proving the following two inequalities
Following equations and inequalities are given :
$A=V+U$, $B=V-U$, $-\pi/2<U<\pi/2$, $-\pi/2<V<\pi/2$ and $U<V$
Prove that $0<B<\pi$ and $B-\pi<A<\pi-B$
So far I have just concluded the following:
since $U<V$ therefore $0<V-U \implies 0<B$

$0<B=V-U\leq |V-U| \leq |V|+|U| \lt \frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi$,
$A-B=(V+U)-(V-U)=2U>2(-\frac{\pi}{2})=-\pi$, $A+B=(V+U)+(V-U)=2V<2(\frac{\pi}{2})=\pi$.
